# cannot read property of undefined javascript and OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, setinterval

I have an object (a function) called 'Game' which has a prototype method called 'gameLoop.' I need this loop to be called in an interval, so I attempt to do this:

```
setInterval(game.gameLoop,setIntervalAmount);
```

but receive a `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined(…)"`

Here is the prototype method:

```
Game.prototype.gameLoop = function()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.save();


    this.context.translate(this.canvas.width/2, this.canvas.height/2);
    this.context.scale(this.camera.scale,this.camera.scale);
    this.context.rotate(this.camera.rotate);
    this.context.translate(this.camera.x,this.camera.y);


    for(var i=0;i<this.objects.length;i++)
    {
        this.objects[i].updateSprite();
        this.objects[i].drawSprite(this.context);         
    }
    this.context.restore();
}
```

I am still having difficulty understanding Object Oriented Programming in Javascript. I had a working version where the function was just a regular function and I passed in a game object. Any ideas?

By the way, here is some additional code that may be helpful.

```
function Sprite(imgg,w,h)
{
    this.img = imgg;
    this.x = 350;//Math.random()*700;
    this.y = 350;//Math.random()*700;
    this.vx = 0;//Math.random()*8-4;
    this.vy = 0;//Math.random()*8-4;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.rotatespeed = 0.01;
    this.rotate = 40;

}
Sprite.prototype.drawSprite = function(ctx)
{

    ctx.save();


    ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.rotate);


    ctx.drawImage(this.img,0,0,this.img.width,this.img.height,-this.width/2,-this.height/2,this.width,this.height);


    ctx.restore();
}
Sprite.prototype.updateSprite = function()
{
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    this.rotate += this.rotatespeed;


    if(this.x > 700)
        this.vx = -this.vx;
    if(this.x < 0)
        this.vx = -this.vy;

    if(this.y > 700)
        this.vy = -this.vy;
    if(this.y < 0)
        this.vy = -this.vy;
}
Sprite.prototype.mouseEventListener = function(evt, type)
{
    console.log("Hello");
}


//------------------------------------------
//GLOBAL VARIALBES

var setIntervalAmount = 30;
var scrollAmount = 0.5;
var game;
function Game()
{
    this.camera = new Object();
    this.camera.x = -350;
    this.camera.y = -350;
    this.camera.scale = 1;

    this.camera.rotate = 0;

    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.canvas.id="mycanvas";
    this.canvas.width = 700;
    this.canvas.height = 700;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");    

    var ctx = this.context;

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

        var canvasX = mouseX * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
        var canvasY = mouseY * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;


        //console.log(canvasX+" | "+canvasY);

    });

    this.objects = new Array();  


}
Game.prototype.handleMouse = function(evt,type)
{
    for(var i=0;i<this.objects.length;i++)
    {
        this.objects[i].mouseEventListener(evt,type);
    }
};

Game.prototype.gameLoop = function()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.save();


    this.context.translate(this.canvas.width/2, this.canvas.height/2);
    this.context.scale(this.camera.scale,this.camera.scale);
    this.context.rotate(this.camera.rotate);
    this.context.translate(this.camera.x,this.camera.y);


    for(var i=0;i<this.objects.length;i++)
    {
        this.objects[i].updateSprite();
        this.objects[i].drawSprite(this.context);         
    }
    this.context.restore();
}


/*Game.prototype.drawGame = function()
{
    var gameLoop = setInterval(function(){

        this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.context.save();


        this.context.translate(this.canvas.width/2, this.canvas.height/2);
        this.context.scale(this.camera.scale,this.camera.scale);
        this.context.rotate(this.camera.rotate);
        this.context.translate(this.camera.x,this.camera.y);


        for(var i=0;i<this.objects.length;i++)
        {
            this.objects[i].updateSprite();
            this.objects[i].drawSprite(this.context);         
        }
        this.context.restore();

    },setIntervalAmount); 

}*/



function mouseWheelListener() 
{
    var evt = window.event;
    console.log(evt.wheelDelta);
    if(evt.wheelDelta < 0)
        game.camera.scale /= (1+scrollAmount);
    else 
        game.camera.scale *= (1+scrollAmount);

}
function mouseDownListener()
{
    var evt = window.event;
    var type = "down"
    game.handleMouse(evt,type);
}
function mouseUpListener()
{
    var evt = window.event;
    var type = "up"
    game.handleMouse(evt,type);
}
function mouseMoveListener()
{
    var evt = window.event;
    var type = "move"
    game.handleMouse(evt,type);
}

//------------------

window.addEventListener('load',function(event){startgame();});

var dog = new Image();
dog.src = "grid.gif";

function startgame()
{
    game = new Game();

    for(var i=0;i<1;i++)
        game.objects.push(new Sprite(dog,250,250));


    setInterval(game.gameLoop,setIntervalAmount);

    document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("wheel", mouseWheelListener);
    document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener);
    document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener);
    document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener);
}
```

Comment: This is because, your context is returning null. Can you try using a null check for the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue, with your code is the context on which you are executing the gameloop method.

usually setInterval, setTimeout functions are executed under the global / window context. Hence, if you specify *this* inside the method, you are technically referring to global context, even though you are executing it on an object.

So, just to make sure you don't run into issues, always have a method as a first argument to setInterval, that would execute the necessary functions, instead of a method reference, something like

```
setInterval(function(){/* 
    game.gameLoop()
*/}, 1000);
```

This way you are executing the setInterval function in the global context but you are calling a method on game object explicitly.

```js
function Sprite(imgg, w, h) {
  this.img = imgg;
  this.x = 350; //Math.random()*700;
  this.y = 350; //Math.random()*700;
  this.vx = 0; //Math.random()*8-4;
  this.vy = 0; //Math.random()*8-4;
  this.width = w;
  this.height = h;
  this.rotatespeed = 0.01;
  this.rotate = 40;

}
Sprite.prototype.drawSprite = function(ctx) {

  ctx.save();


  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.rotate);


  ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.img.width, this.img.height, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);


  ctx.restore();
}
Sprite.prototype.updateSprite = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;

  this.rotate += this.rotatespeed;


  if (this.x > 700)
    this.vx = -this.vx;
  if (this.x < 0)
    this.vx = -this.vy;

  if (this.y > 700)
    this.vy = -this.vy;
  if (this.y < 0)
    this.vy = -this.vy;
}
Sprite.prototype.mouseEventListener = function(evt, type) {
  //console.log("Hello");
}


//------------------------------------------
////GLOBAL VARIALBES

var setIntervalAmount = 200;
var scrollAmount = 0.5;
var game;

function Game() {
  this.camera = new Object();
  this.camera.x = -350;
  this.camera.y = -350;


  this.camera.scale = 1;

  this.camera.rotate = 0;

  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
  this.canvas.id = "mycanvas";
  this.canvas.width = 700;
  this.canvas.height = 700;
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

  var ctx = this.context;

  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

    var canvasX = mouseX * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
    var canvasY = mouseY * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;


    //console.log(canvasX+" | "+canvasY);

  });

  this.objects = new Array();


}
Game.prototype.handleMouse = function(evt, type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++) {
    this.objects[i].mouseEventListener(evt, type);
  }
};

Game.prototype.gameLoop = function() {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  this.context.save();


  this.context.translate(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2);
  this.context.scale(this.camera.scale, this.camera.scale);
  this.context.rotate(this.camera.rotate);
  this.context.translate(this.camera.x, this.camera.y);


  for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++) {
    this.objects[i].updateSprite();
    this.objects[i].drawSprite(this.context);
  }
  this.context.restore();
}


/*Game.prototype.drawGame = function()
{
    var gameLoop = setInterval(function(){

        this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.context.save();


        this.context.translate(this.canvas.width/2, this.canvas.height/2);
        this.context.scale(this.camera.scale,this.camera.scale);
        this.context.rotate(this.camera.rotate);
        this.context.translate(this.camera.x,this.camera.y);


        for(var i=0;i<this.objects.length;i++)
        {
            this.objects[i].updateSprite();
            this.objects[i].drawSprite(this.context);         
        }
        this.context.restore();

    },setIntervalAmount); 

}*/



function mouseWheelListener() {
  var evt = window.event;
  console.log(evt.wheelDelta);
  if (evt.wheelDelta < 0)
    game.camera.scale /= (1 + scrollAmount);
  else
    game.camera.scale *= (1 + scrollAmount);

}

function mouseDownListener() {
  var evt = window.event;
  var type = "down"
  game.handleMouse(evt, type);
}

function mouseUpListener() {
  var evt = window.event;
  var type = "up"
  game.handleMouse(evt, type);
}

function mouseMoveListener() {
  var evt = window.event;
  var type = "move"
  game.handleMouse(evt, type);
}

//------------------

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  startgame();
});

var dog = new Image();
dog.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0mIA.png";

function startgame() {
  game = new Game();

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    game.objects.push(new Sprite(dog, 250, 250));


  setInterval(function() {
    game.gameLoop();
  }, setIntervalAmount);


  document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("wheel", mouseWheelListener);
  document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener);
  document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener);
  document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener);
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you for your help! I am still having a hard time grasping this concept though... I am familiar with Java/C++ but Javascript and this functions are driving my brain crazy!

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will call `game.gameloop` at the global scope which means the value of `this` inside the function is not what you expect it to be. This can be fixed by binding the function to the desired object.

E.g. change `setInterval(game.gameLoop,setIntervalAmount);` to `setInterval(game.gameLoop.bind(game),setIntervalAmount);`.

This [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) may provide some clarity for your code's current behaviour:

```
this.x = 9; 
var module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() { return this.x; }
};

module.getX(); // 81

var retrieveX = module.getX;
retrieveX();   
// returns 9 - The function gets invoked at the global scope

// Create a new function with 'this' bound to module
// New programmers might confuse the
// global var x with module's property x
var boundGetX = retrieveX.bind(module);
boundGetX(); // 81
```